# Invalid Decimal:null while running test class

Tags: apex, trigger

Below is my trigger. For the trigger i have written a test class. While running the test class i am getting `invalide decimal:null` in line

Error:

```
    System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id a022C000001BcFdQAK; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, TotalInvesntmentvalue: execution of AfterDelete 
caused by: System.TypeException: Invalid decimal: null

Trigger.TotalInvesntmentvalue: line 15, column 1: []
```

Trigger

```
   trigger TotalInvesntmentvalue on Investment__c (after delete, after insert, after update, after undelete) {  
  if (Trigger.isDelete)  
  {  
  for (Investment__c E : Trigger.old)  
    {  
      Smart_Account__c M = [select name, Investment_Value__c from Smart_Account__c where id =:E.Smart_Account__c];  
      AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [select sum(Value__c)aver from Investment__c where Smart_Account__c=: M.id];  
      Decimal decimalRevenue = 0;  
      if(groupedResults.size() > 0)
      {  
        String str = '' + groupedResults[0].get('aver') ; 

              decimalRevenue = Decimal.ValueOf(str) ; 

        System.debug('decimalRevenue ::::: ' + decimalRevenue) ;  
      } 
      M.Investment_Value__c = decimalRevenue;  
      update M;  
    }  
  }  
  else  
  {  
  for (Investment__c E : Trigger.new)  
    {  
      Smart_Account__c M = [select name, Investment_Value__c from Smart_Account__c where id =:E.Smart_Account__c];  
      AggregateResult[]  groupedResults = [select sum(Value__c)aver from Investment__c where Smart_Account__c=: M.id];  
      Decimal decimalRevenue = 0;  
      if(groupedResults.size() > 0)  
      {  
        String str = '' + groupedResults[0].get('aver') ;  
        decimalRevenue = Decimal.ValueOf(str) ;  
        System.debug('decimalRevenue ::::: ' + decimalRevenue) ;  
      }  
      M.Investment_Value__c = decimalRevenue;  
      update M;  
    }  
  }  
  }

Value__c is a formula field..
```

Test class -

```
@isTest
public class SMI_Investmentmgmttest {

    private static testMethod void testmethod1() {



        Smart_Account__c s = new Smart_Account__c();
        s.Name ='test';
        insert s;

        Smart_Fund__c sf = new Smart_Fund__c();
        sf.Name = 'test';
        sf.Symbol__c='wer';
        sf.Price__c=100;
        insert sf;

        Investment__c inv = new Investment__c();
        inv.Name = 'test';
        inv.Smart_Account__c = s.id;
        inv.Smart_Fund__c = sf.id;
        insert inv;

        delete inv;

    }

}
```

Comment: In which line? Can you add the full error message?

Comment: hi.. I have updated my code..

Comment: I think it's because you're trying to access Trigger.old when you're trigger is in an After delete context.. So basically after the  Investment__c has been deleted, the groupedResults var don't return nothing, and therefor the `str` variable is null.  Try changing the trigger context to `Before Delete` instead `After Delete` in the header.

Comment: i am updating another object value in after delete ..

Comment: Have you reviewed the debug log output? Can you paste the relevant portion in your questions. I do not see an opportunity for the value of the decimal to be null in the code you posted as the decimal.valueOf() should throw the error and you set it to 0 initially so.. . Then there is the fact that it breaks every best practice there is

Comment: debug log - 07:09:21.0 (346562628)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[26]|System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id a022C000001BcHoQAK; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, TotalInvesntmentvalue: execution of AfterDelete 
caused by: System.TypeException: Invalid decimal: null

Comment: I believe the error occurs here: `decimalRevenue = Decimal.ValueOf(str) ; ` : str isn't a decimal type but rather a null. The problem is (I think) because the the trigger's context is after delete, and after you delete something it won't have any value..

Comment: @user2542953 , Why won't you do the same thing with before delete? Why Is the 'after' so important?

Comment: Ahh, I misread the error as being from the DML on update and not for the DML from the trigger. However, according to the error (in Original post not edited version) line 15 was the DML line `update M`  when copied from the code the OP posted so......

Answer (score 4):

SUM returns a decimal, so there's no need to convert it to a string, then back to a decimal. You can simply do this:

```
if(groupedResults.size() > 0) {
    M.Investment_Value__c = (Decimal)groupedResults[0].get('aver');
}
```

Specifically, what's happening in your original code is that 'aver' is null, so Str ends up being the string "null" (not a null value, but rather a four-letter string with the word "null" in it), basically:

```
String str = '' + null;
```

Decimal.valueOf didn't know how to handle the string "null", because it's not a decimal value, so you end up with the exception thrown.

Comment: But @sfdcfox, this don't resolve the problem. As I said in previous comments, the problem starts when you're trying to sum an after-deleted record that will always return null..

Comment: @YonatanGoriachnick No, this is a standard design for custom roll-up summary logic. Using before delete would have incorrect values, because the uery would include the not-yet-deleted records. Granted, there are other problems with the code, but this answer resolves the immediate problem.